# Using SelectLayerByAttribute with list of values in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, list

I'm fairly new to python, so I'm having a little trouble with this. I want to iterate through a list of values, select the list values from a feature class, select from another feature class that intersects the first selection, and then calculate a field in the second selection based of the list index value. Here's the script I'm working on:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:workspace.gdb"

circuits = ["DC430", "DC431", "DC432"]

for i in range(len(circuits)):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Meters", "NEW_SELECTION", circuits[i])
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Parcels", "INTERSECT", "Meters", "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("Parcels", "Circuit", "circuits[i]", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

How do I make this work the right way?

Comment: Select works on Layer. So use make feature layer and use SQL inside. Use select by location on newly created layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your list of circuits and then create an SQL that matches the format you'd see in an [ArcMap selection](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).

For text fields in a file geodatabase:

```
YOURFIELDNAME = 'FIELD VALUE'
```

Your code would be something like this:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:workspace.gdb"

circuits = ["DC430", "DC431", "DC432"]
circuitFieldName = "YOURFIELDNAMEHERE"

for circuit in circuits:
    sql = "{} = '{}'".format (circuitFieldName, circuit)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Meters", "NEW_SELECTION", sql)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Parcels", "INTERSECT", "Meters")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("Parcels", circuitFieldName, '"{}"'.format (circuit))
```

Comment: Create layer is missing.

Comment: @ecartrace don’t forget to mark the answer as correct then.

Comment: Hi sir, I know my comment is too late. But would you care to explain what the "{} = '{}'".format is please? It seems like I see it on this sub from time to time. What's it called and how can I read up more on it? Thanks.

Comment: @Emil The first part of the string format() sql expression has the correct syntax, i.e., the quotes are correct - good work, and thanks!